# Passing an object to a function, scope, and destructors

Tags: c++, oop

Recently I've been getting back into programming in C++ and have come across interesting while programming something else.

In the code below I defined a class with a pointer member that gets deleted in the class' destructor.

I have also defined a function which takes a Test_Object object as an argument which calls one of the get_val() method which does nothing more but report the value held in the memory address the pointer is pointing to.

Now when I call the function twice it correctly prints the value in held by the internal pointer correctly once, then just core dumps after the second.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the reason this happens is because after the first time the function is called the object's destructor is called because the object has gone out of scope and is essentially destroyed.

The only way I could think of preventing this is by passing the object by reference. Is there any other way to prevent this from happening? It seems a bit dangerous to simply pass the object by reference since the object can be modified in that function call which could lead to headaches later on.

I've tried making the argument const, however I get an error stating that ‘const Test_Object’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void Test_Object::get_val()’ discards qualifiers argument.get_val();

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test_Object
{
    private:
    int *internal_pointer;
    public:
    Test_Object(int value)
    {
        internal_pointer = new int;
        *internal_pointer = value;
    }
    ~Test_Object() 
    {
        delete internal_pointer;
        internal_pointer = NULL;
    }
    void get_val() { cout<<*internal_pointer<<endl; }
};

void test_outsider(Test_Object argument)
{
    argument.get_val();
}

int main()
{
    Test_Object test = Test_Object(4);
    test_outsider(test);
    test_outsider(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to define copy constructor and copy assignment operator, or, in this case, just use `int` instead of pointer to `int`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment about the copy and copy assignment operator. About the use of a pointer, the above code is just was a test I created when I found a bug in my code that dealt with objects that really did need a pointer member to an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you should read about [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

As for your problems it's because the objects are *copied*, and since you don't provide your own copy-constructor the pointer is copied "as-is" leaving multiple copies pointing to the same allocated memory. When one of those copies `delete` the allocated memory in the destructor, the pointer is invalidated for all copies.

You can solve the problem by implementing a copy-constructor and a copy-assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you for the link and answer. That definitely solved the problem. Ill keep this in mind in the future